# Large accounting table, best way to partitioning by two dates

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

I need to create a log table to stores the connections to out network (last 3 years, after that the log will go into backup). The hardware/software used is proprietary, and for accounting it just call our custom script with some arguments like this:

- when a user connects (`our_script START user mac ip`);
- when a user disconnects (`our_script STOP user mac ip in_bytes out_bytes more`)

Sometimes we do not receive the disconnect message. So we need to adapt to this.

So far I came up with this structure for the accounting table:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounting` (
  `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mac` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ipv6` varchar(39) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stop_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `in_bytes` bigint(32) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `out_bytes` bigint(32) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `more_columns` varchar(255) default NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`mac`,`ip`,`start_datetime`,`stop_datetime`),
  KEY `prim_ipv6` (`user`,`mac`,`ipv6`,`start_datetime`,`stop_datetime`),
  KEY `user` (`user`) USING HASH,
  KEY `mac` (`mac`) USING HASH,
  KEY `ip` (`ip`) USING HASH,
  KEY `ipv6` (`ipv6`) USING HASH,
  KEY `start_datetime` (`start_datetime`),
  KEY `stop_datetime` (`stop_datetime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query used for writing are (these needs to be real fast):

- when a user connects a simple insert
- when a user disconnects `update accounting set stop_datetime=now(), in_bytes=$in_bytes, out_bytes=$out_bytes, more_columns=$more where user="$user" and ip="$ip" and stop_datetime="0000-00-00 00:00:00" order by start_datetime DESC limit 1;`, this is a workaround in the case we have more then one row for start, we just update the last start.

A better workaround, is to update the stop_datetime for rows without it, at every start, and use another column for storing that this is not a normal stop, I think I will go with the second workaround.

We have 2 ways to select from this table (this could be slower max 1 - 2 sec):

- select the last 50 connection for a user: `select ... where user="$user" order by start_datetime DESC limit 50;`, for this the user HASH key is handy, beacause AFAIK HASH is better than BTREE for equality.
- select witch user was connected with ip=$ip on date=$date `select ... where ip="$ip" and $date between start_datetime and stop_datetime;`

This table will hold between 0.5 to 1 bilion rows, that's why I thought to partition it.
The best option is to partition it by month, but I have 2 relevant dates, and at the begining/end of the month start will be in one partition, stop will be in another.

The questions:

- Witch is the best way to do partitions, by start_datetime, by stop_datetime, by start_datetime with subpartitions for stop_datetime ?
- Do I realy need to partitionate ?
- Do you have any other suggestion on how to improve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Use InnoDB engine - it provides row-level locks and is faster for insert/update intensive applications. You don't need index on user, since it's the left-most field in the primary key and primary key can be used to resolve any query filtered by user. I guess prim_ipv6 has to be UNIQUE, as the primary key is unique and this is the v6 version of pk

Comment: @Darhazer Unfortunately I can't use InnoDB, but according to dev.mysql: "For MyISAM tables, if there are no free blocks in the middle of the data file, concurrent SELECT and INSERT statements are supported", I was assigned to another project, now i'm back to this, I am redesigning and I will update the question in the following days.

Answer (score 2):

Since stop_datetime will not be known at insert time the partition must be done by start_datetime.

I think partitioning by day (`date_format(start_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')`) would be adequate since 1 billion rows divided by (3 years * 365 days) ≃ 900,000 rows per partition

Updating indexes is expensive and it happens at inserts, updates and deletes. Keep the indexes to a minimum. If the main queries will be those selects then I would keep the primary key like the following and trash all the other keys:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`start_datetime`,`stop_datetime`,`mac`,`ip`)
```

Comment: I'm redesigning, I will drop the update, use a single "insert select from another_table (max 40K rows)", partition by date is not possible because mysql has a limit of 1024 partition per table while 3*365=1095. I also had a problem with primary key, stop_datetime did not fit in, it seems that the key had a limit, but documentation says 1000 bytes, my test had 65 bytes ... didn't find out why. I saw this in the experiment logs: duplicate entry "some_user-00:11:22:33:44:55-100.200.10.20-2012-03-05 08:12:58-2" for key primary

Answer (score 2):

PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`mac`,`ip`,`start_datetime`,`stop_datetime`),

KEY `prim_ipv6` (`user`,`mac`,`ipv6`,`start_datetime`,`stop_datetime`),

The second one is totally redundant, DROP it.  (A PRIMARY KEY is a KEY!)

MyISAM does not have HASH indexing; you were probably given BTree, which is nearly as good.

where user="$user" and ip="$ip" and stop_datetime="0000-00-00 00:00:00" order by start_datetime DESC limit 1 -- 
That begs for this index:

INDEX(user, ip, stop_datetime, start_datetime)

where user="$user" order by start_datetime DESC limit 50 --
begs for INDEX(user, start_datetime)

This is very hard to optimize:
where ip="$ip" and $date between start_datetime and stop_datetime

Suggest adding:
INDEX(ip, start_datetime), INDEX(stop_datetime)

PARTITIONing will not help unless you can take advantage of "partition pruning".

Since most of these queries include ip="$ip", and then get into trouble with timestamps, it might be best to partition on ip.  I would not do more than 64 partitions; there are inefficiencies otherwise.

Do not (usually) put the "partition key" first in the PRIMARY KEY.

Because of your "inside-out" use of start/end times, I don't think the timestamps would be useful for partitioning.

> `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     `ipv6` varchar(39) DEFAULT NULL,

How are you dealing with that?  I think the standard says that this is how to encode ipv4 in IPv6 format:

::ffff:123.123.123.123

Perhaps you should switch to that, and abandon the `ip` column.